# Apply "permutations" of a function over a list

Tags: list, haskell

Creating the *permutations* of a list or set is simple enough. I need to apply a function to each element of all subsets of all elements in a list, in the order in which they occur. For instance:

```
apply f [x,y] = { [x,y], [f x, y], [x, f y], [f x, f y] }
```

The code I have is a monstrous pipeline or expensive computations, and I'm not sure how to proceed, or if it's correct. I'm sure there must be a better way to accomplish this task - perhaps in the list monad - but I'm not sure. This is my code:

```
apply :: Ord a => (a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> Set [a]
apply p xs = let box = take (length xs + 1) . map (take $ length xs) in
  (Set.fromList . map (catMaybes . zipWith (flip ($)) xs) . concatMap permutations
   . box . map (flip (++) (repeat Just)) . flip iterate []) ((:) p)
```

The general idea was:

```
(1) make the list 
      [[], [f], [f,f], [f,f,f], ... ]
(2) map (++ repeat Just) over the list to obtain
      [[Just, Just, Just, Just, ... ],
       [f   , Just, Just, Just, ... ],
       [f   , f   , Just, Just, ... ],
                                ... ]
(3) find all permutations of each list in (2) shaved to the length of the input list        
(4) apply the permuted lists to the original list, garnering all possible applications
    of the function f to each (possibly empty) subset of the original list, preserving
    the original order.
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do it, though. I just don't know it. This way is expensive, messy, and rather prone to error. The Justs are there because of the intended application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do this, you can leverage the fact that lists represent non-deterministic values when using applicatives and monads. It then becomes as simple as:

```
apply f = mapM (\x -> [x, f x])
```

It basically reads as follows: "Map each item in a list to itself and the result of applying f to it. Finally, return a list of all the possible combinations of these two values across the whole list."

Comment: Of the two top answers, it was hard to choose which to accept. This answer required more work for me to understand, but overall led to a better understanding of the list monad. It's an interesting and, now, obvious solution to the problem.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your problem correctly, it's best not to describe it in terms of permutations.  Rather, it's closer to generating powersets.

```
powerset (x:xs) = let pxs = powerset xs in pxs ++ map (x :) pxs
powerset []     = [[]]
```

Each time you add another member to the head of the list, the powerset doubles in size.  The second half of the powerset is exactly like the first, but with x included.

For your problem, the choice is not whether to include or exclude x, but whether to apply or not apply f.

```
powersetapp f (x:xs) = let pxs = powersetapp f xs in map (x:) pxs ++ map (f x:) pxs
powersetapp f []     = [[]]
```

This does what your "apply" function does, modulo making a Set out of the result.

Answer (score 3):

Paul's and Heatsink's answers are good,  but error out when you try to run them on infinite lists.

Here's a different method that works on both infinite and finite lists:

```
apply _ [] = [ [] ]
apply f (x:xs) = (x:ys):(x':ys):(double yss)
  where x' = f x
        (ys:yss) = apply f xs
        double [] = []
        double (ys:yss) = (x:ys):(x':ys):(double yss)
```

This works as expected - though you'll note it produces a different order to the permutations than Paul's and Heatsink's

```
ghci> -- on an infinite list
ghci> map (take 4) $ take 16 $ apply (+1) [0,0..]
[[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],...,[1,1,1,1]]
ghci> -- on a finite list
ghci> apply (+1) [0,0,0,0]
[[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],...,[1,1,1,1]]
```

Comment: If by "work", you mean that all lists with a finite number of function applications will be produced.  The infinite list `map f xs` will never be produced when `xs` is infinite.   Exercise: is it possible to make one where *all* combinations are produced?  (That's right, it's an exercise in a comment!  The audacity!)

Comment: There is no implementation of `apply` that will generate all the combinations in countable time.  Consider the sequence `apply (+1) [0,0..]`.  If we consider each list in the sequence a list of coefficients `[a_i]` for `a_1 (1/2)^1 + a_2 (1/2)^2 + ... + a_i (1/2)^i +...` then there exists a bijection between elements of the sequence and the real numbers between 0 and 1 inclusive.  However, by Cantor, there are an uncountable number of reals in that range, so there is no way to generate all the elements of the sequence in countable time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative phrasing of rampion's infinite-input-handling solution:

```
-- sequence a list of nonempty lists
sequenceList :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sequenceList [] = [[]]
sequenceList (m:ms) = do
    xs <- nonempty (sequenceList ms)
    x  <- nonempty m
    return (x:xs)
  where
    nonempty ~(x:xs) = x:xs
```

Then we can define `apply` in Paul's idiomatic style:

```
apply f = sequenceList . map (\x -> [x, f x])
```

Contrast `sequenceList` with the usual definition of `sequence`:

```
sequence :: (Monad m) => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence [] = [[]]
sequence (m:ms) = do
    x <- m
    xs <- sequence ms
    return (x:xs)
```

The order of binding is reversed in `sequenceList` so that the variations of the first element are the "inner loop", i.e. we vary the head faster than the tail.  Varying the end of an infinite list is a waste of time.

The other key change is `nonempty`, the promise that we won't bind an empty list.  If any of the inputs were empty, or if the result of the recursive call to `sequenceList` were ever empty, then we would be forced to return an empty list.  We can't tell in advance whether any  of inputs is empty (because there are infinitely many of them to check), so the only way for this function to output anything at all is to promise that they won't be.

Anyway, this is fun subtle stuff.  Don't stress about it on your first day :-)

Comment: cool stuff! I had to look up what the tilde meant though: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness#Lazy_pattern_matching